# Google Apps Directory API - Change primary domain with secondary domain

Tags: google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have a Google Apps Free Account with one primary domain and an secondary domain.

Recently I came across Google Admin SDK Directory API, where the option to switch the primary domains is available through the API.

[Directory API - Customer Update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/customers/update)

I used the "Try Now" section to use the API, I did log in and I authorized with appropriate scopes and provided following properties,

**customerKey** - **my_customer**

in **Request Body**

**{"customerDomain":"domainB.com"}**

but got following response,

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Input"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Input"
 }
}
```

Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Free / Standard Edition [does not support secondary domains](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295?hl=en) and thus does not support change of primary / secondary domain.

Additionally, primary domain change does not work if you registered the domain with Google, you'll need to transfer to a different domain registrar first.

See [Google's help article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301932?hl=en) for other considerations.

Comment: This secondary domain were added during initial days when it was available, and i have tried the same with another account and it was working fine. But this API doesn't tell what is the actual problem

Comment: We upgraded to Google Apps for Work and tried, still no difference same error.

Comment: updated response, may be the case if you registered the domain with Google via GoDaddy or eNom.